# Unable to add view in callback method & getting error "UnauthorizedAccessException" in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am new to Windows Phone 7 & C#. I am facing problem for navigation to new screen. My requirement is i need to Check login credentials to server & if OK then move on to next screen. But i am getting error as **"UnauthorizedAccessException"**- "Invalid cross-thread access". .

Find Code below

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
    }   

  private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) 
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        if (response.StatusCode  == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/tabview.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Comment: For who will stuck for such thing Used "Dispatcher Class" as it deals with UI thread & need to use to update any UI part in non UI Thread. Replaced code in _if_ block
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/tabview.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));

Comment: Does that mean you solved your own issue?

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP has fixed his issue, [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8/) MSDN article explains the rationale behind this in detail.